Using OAuth2 in VBA
I have an MS Access desktop application which generates Invoices and I would like to be able to post the details directly into our Xero account. I did have this function working under OAuth but not since the move to OAuth2.
Does anybody have example code for this which they are willing to share?
Looking forward...
Brian
I have looked at a number of examples found via web searches but haven't found one with enough explanation to enable me to modify for my purposes.

maybe you will find help in this site https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Thanks, I will have a look. This is proving to be quite a mission!
